# Странность или ошибка в mod_rewrite/.htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Cледующее правило в .htaccess

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

при обращении к url вида

```
http://example.com/something
```

редиректит на

```
http://www./something
```

т.е. RewriteCond срабатывает, но ничего не передает. Кто-нибудь подскажет - в чем тут ошибка?

Сразу поправлюсь - вариант с

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

и прочие подобные варианты работают, это понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема оказывается в том, что при отрицании нельзя использовать $N или %N. 
Пример выше работать будет если только непосредственно использовать %{HTTP_HOST} в RewriteRule:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Это и есть ответ, собственно. Вопрос закрыт )